# how to sum column using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sum

I'm trying to sum column from the editable textbox(popover?)

[image: table]

[image: pop up]

What I'm trying to do is to sum.

Kehadiran+tugas+UTS+Uas = total and if "Total" > 80 then Nilai = A.

The table is connected to MySQL database.

```php
    <?php
    
    include('database_connection.php');
    
    $column = array("Id_krs", "NIM_krs_Mhs","Nama" , "Kode_Matakuliah_krs", "Semester_Ambil", "Kehadiran","Tugas", "UTS", "UAS", "Total", "Nilai", "Mutu");
    
    //$sum = array_sum(array_column($Kehadiran,$Tugas,$UTS,$UAS 'Total'));
```

Since I'm a very bad/beginner at Php, try so many options, just can't get it to work. have no idea how to use the code.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

edit code from fetch.php:

```
<?php

include('database_connection.php');

$column = array("Id_krs", "NIM_krs_Mhs","Nama_Mahasiswa" , "Kode_Matakuliah_krs", "Semester_Ambil", "Kehadiran","Tugas", "UTS", "UAS", "Total", "Nilai", "Mutu");

$query = "
SELECT * FROM krs INNER JOIN mahasiswa ON NIM=NIM_krs_Mhs
";

if(isset($_POST['filter_kelas'], $_POST['filter_Kode']) && $_POST['filter_kelas'] != '' && $_POST['filter_Kode'] != '')
{
 $query .= '
 WHERE Kode_krs_Kelas = "'.$_POST['filter_kelas'].'" AND Kode_Matakuliah_krs = "'.$_POST['filter_Kode'].'" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY NIM_krs_Mhs ASC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();



$data = array();

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row['Id_krs'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['NIM_krs_Mhs'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Nama_Mahasiswa'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Kode_Matakuliah_krs'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Semester_Ambil'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Kehadiran'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Tugas'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['UTS'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['UAS'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Total'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Nilai'];
    $sub_array[] = $row['Mutu'];
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM krs INNER JOIN mahasiswa ON NIM=NIM_krs_Mhs";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 "draw"       =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"   =>  count_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered"  =>  $number_filter_row,
 "data"       =>  $data
);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to sum specific columns in the array, let's suppose the columns array here represent the data in the same sequence

```
$column = array("Id_krs", "NIM_krs_Mhs","Nama" , "Kode_Matakuliah_krs", "Semester_Ambil", "Kehadiran","Tugas", "UTS", "UAS", "Total", "Nilai", "Mutu");
```

so to sum (Kehadiran+tugas+UTS+Uas)

then it will become like this

```
$total = $column[5] + $column[6] + $column[7] + $column[8];
```

also, you can sum these numbers from the database add this to your select query

```
(Kehadiran + Tugas + UTS + UAS) AS total
```

Comment: no luck when trying to implement di code. since i have 3 .php file that connected to the database, and have no clue where to put to.
we got, fetch.php. index.php, and update.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = array_sum([$Kehadiran, $tugas, $UTS, $Uas])

if ($total >  80) {
  $nilai = 'A'
}
```

Comment: no luck when trying to implement di code. since i have 3 .php file that connected to the database, and have no clue where to put to.
we got, fetch.php. index.php, and update.php

Comment: @Noisyheaven can you provide how you fetch from your database

Comment: .done. thank you for helping btw. still not yet to managed to find the correct code

@kennard

Comment: @Noisyheaven Can I see the repository

Comment: sorry, i don't understand.. so the code should be working at the fetch.php?